# UI column reordered DataGrid data into DataTable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I have a `WPF` `DatagGrid`, in which user can sort items and reorder columns.

Now I want to copy the exact `DataGrid` data to a `DataTable`, data which is shown in `DataGrid` after reordering items and sorting columns.

Copying `Datagrid.ItemSource` to `DataTable` is not helping here.

I am binding `DataGrid` to a `DataTable` which usually have 100 columns and more than 50 rows, Now I just want to save reordered data ( done by user on `UI` by dragging columns ) into a new seperate `DataTable`.

Comment: A first starting point would be to get the sorted columns and their order and the column display index.

Comment: A first starting point would be to get the sorted columns and their order and the column display index.
The first you can get from the DataGrid.Items.SortDescriptions collection and the second with DataGrid.Columns collection where each DataGridColumn contained in this collection has a DisplayIndex property telling at which column position this column is displayed.
Perhaps the ordering and sorting of columns is reflected in the DataTable.DefaultView. If yes you could try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317416/get-filtered-data-from-dataset-to-datatable

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to keep track of user actions (column dragging, ordering) and build new SQL query to data source.

Comment: Idea is great but this is not the optimal solution. When I want to save that time only I should be able to save it into `DataTable`.